# How can I create a matrix by permutating a vector in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have matrix two matrixes:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = np.zeros((4,8))
```

So, how can I have a matrix C, with a format like this:

```
C=[[1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4],[3,4,0,0,0,0,1,2]]
```

Comment: you don't need numpy here you can generate matrix C using only matrix A

Comment: I would also use numpy for this if it needs to be flexible. Have a look at `numpy.roll` method: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html

Comment: @ypnos I really got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following solution without numpy, but i appreciate if you have smarter version using numpy then feel free to highlight

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]

matrix = [A]
for shift in range(3):
    A = A[-2:] + A[:-2]
    matrix.append(A)

print(matrix)
```

> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
> 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]]

Answer (score 1):

Silly Friday answer;

```
from collections import deque

A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [0,0,0,0]
AB = deque(A+B)

C = [list(AB) for i in range(4) if not AB.rotate(2*bool(i))]
```